# Understanding the mixed Hodge structure on D-modules on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, d-modules, vanishing-cycles

Consider the category of regular D-modules on $\mathbb{C}$ (let's say as a complex manifold).  It's a well-known fact that if you consider the subcategory of these where the singular support is the union of the zero section and cotangent fiber over 0, and the monodromy around the origin is unipotent, then this is equivalent to the category of $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces $V,W$ and maps $A\colon V\to W$ and $B\colon W\to V$ such that $AB$ (or equivalently $BA$) is nilpotent.

What I would like to find a reference for is the mixed Hodge version of this statement.  I'm reasonably sure this should go something like:

> There is a full subcategory of ($\mathbb{R}$-)mixed Hodge modules on the manifold $\mathbb C$ (maybe characterized by something like having Tate mixed Hodge structures on the stalks and vanishing cycles) which is equivalent to the category of graded $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces $V, W$, and degree 1 maps $A\colon V\to W$ and $B\colon W\to V$.

Note, the graded condition implies that $AB$ has degree 2, and thus is automatically nilpotent.  This seems like one of the first exercises one should do to make sure one understands mixed Hodge modules properly, so I'm hoping to find a reasonable write up of it somewhere (or I guess maybe here, if someone is inspired to write it).

Comment: Yes, certainly you should restrict to the subcategory of modules of Tate type to get such an equivalence. I'm not aware of an explicit statement like that in the literature, but I think one can extract it with a bit of work. I can try to write something in few days when I have more time.

Comment: @DonuArapura The notion of Hodge quivers in these notes of yours: https://www.math.purdue.edu/~arapura/preprints/tifr.pdf was basically what I had in mind.  For the application I'm interested in, I think that was basically enough information.

Comment: OK, sounds good.